# Why is prolog confused by my input file

Tags: prolog

I'm writing a list of lists to a file with

```
choice(2, X):- 
  nl, write('\tRead roster from a file:'),nl, write('\tEnter file name: '),read(N),
  open(N,write,Stream), write(Stream, X), nl(Stream),close(Stream), write('\tRoster stored.'),nl,nl,menu(X).
```

then I'm reading it with

```
choice(1, X):- 
  nl, write('\tStore roster to a file:'),nl, write('\tEnter file name: '),read(N),
  open(N,read,Stream), read(Stream, Y), close(Stream), write('\tRoster stored.'),nl,nl,menu(Y).
```

this is the contents of a sample from choice(2,X) that I tried to read with choice(1,X).

```
[[[49,48,48],[100,97,109,105,101,110],100]]
```

when I try to read it gives the error

```
ERROR: r2:1:44: Syntax error: Unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 3):

You get this error because `read/2` can only read full prolog terms terminated with `.`. Contents of your file aren't terminated with dot, so end of file is "unexpected".

My suggestion is that you should modify that:

```
open(N,read,Stream), read(Stream, Y), close(Stream)
```

Into that:

```
open(N,read,Stream), read_line_to_codes(Stream, Codes), close(Stream), atom_codes(Atom, Codes), atom_to_term(Atom, Y, [])
```

Above code reads one line of character data, converts it to atom and then converts it to prolog term unified with Y.

This is my input and output from interpreter to prove it works:

```
?- open('test2.txt',read,Stream), read_line_to_codes(Stream, Codes), close(Stream), atom_codes(Atom, Codes), atom_to_term(Atom, List, []).

List = [[[49, 48, 48], [100, 97, 109, 105, 101, 110], 100]].
```

Contents of file `test2.txt`: `[[[49,48,48],[100,97,109,105,101,110],100]]`

(no dot on the end)

Answer (score 3):

As @Grzegorz correctly said, to be able to read a term with `read` it needs to end with a full stop.

But I don't think that a correct solution to your problem is to read as codes. I think the better way is just to write full stop to the file.

The recommended way, I believe, is to use `write_term` with `fullstop(true)` option instead of `write`. But this is not working on my version of SWI-Prolog.

The easiest way is just to write full stop explicitly with `write(Stream, '.')`.

Comment: @PauloMoura `write(Stream, .)` works for me. Is it really a syntax error on some system?

Comment: Good question. Not in any of the systems I have installed (a large number of them, all up-to-date or recent versions). My reading of the ISO Prolog standard is that `write(.)` is valid syntax. I think I remember long ago to have some issues in some systems with writing a dot without single quotes, hence the habit of always writing `'.'`.

Comment: `write(.)` and `write(Stream, .)` are accepted in GNU and SWI Prolog, which are the ones I have installed.